# Session not created error while running selenium with Chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While running Selenium 2.53 with Chrome 53.0 browser it gives an error as below :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
 (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'HILP39', ip: '172.16.2.76', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

While the same Selenium 2.53 is working fine with Firefox and IE.

I am using simple code as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Sel_test1\\sel_test1\\lib\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

I tried with latest Selenium 3.0 with latest Chrome driver 2.24. Still I was unable to resolve the error.

Can anyone please help to resolve this blocking error?

Comment: did you mentioned correct path for chromedriver.exe?

Comment: yes...i double checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again download the latest version of chromedriver from below link

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

and then try with below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Drivers\\cd\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeDriver d1 = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    d1.manage().window().maximize();
    d1.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=yXmMV66oLIKEoAPx-ZXQDA");
    String pagetitle=d1.getTitle();
```

today itself i tried.